# css растянуть родительский с учетом scaleX дочернего элемента

Tags: css, transform, stylus, width

В Javascript есть getComputedStyle, с которым можно получить то, что отобразилось... но как в чистом css (или stylus) родительскому элементу учесть растянутость scaleX дочернего элемента?

```css
.dd {
  width: 400px;
  border: 2px dotted olive;
  display: flex;
}

.ss {
  width: min-content;
  border: 2px solid red;
}

.ll {
  border: 1px solid aqua;
  white-space: nowrap;
  display: inline-block;
  width: min-content;
  transform-origin: left;
  transform: scaleX(1.5);
}

.ii {
  width: 100%;
  display: inline-block;
}
```

```html
<div class='dd'>
  <span class='ss'>
    <label class='ll' for='ii'>jkjkh gfdgf</label>
  </span>
  <input type='text' id='ii' class='ii' />
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

При помощи одного CSS это нельзя, поскольку в этом вся прелесть свойства `transform` — оно выделяет блок в отдельный слой и потому он никак не влияет на расчеты композитного слоя.

Comment: а можно, например, как-то сделать calc(100% * scaleX) ? (т.е. 100%*1.5) для родительского

Comment: у вас значение scaleX статическое или по какому-то правилу и всегда разное?

Comment: есть ряд div с label в них, для каждой label своe scaleX значение. И проверил, нужно не 100%*1.5 а min-content*1.5 ... - но так вряд ли можно, даже с stylus, верно?

Comment: во-первых, с препроцессорами нельзя ничего такого, чего нельзя без, они не расширяют цсс, во-вторых, `min-content` нельзя запихнуть в `calc()`.

Comment: мое мнение по данному примеру такое — вам надо пересмотреть решение и, как минимум, не растягивать по одной оси блоки с текстом.

Comment: спасибо, понятно. в моем макете верстки нужно растягивать labelы, а за ними input сразу идет...

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/57686/discussion-between-sasha-omelchenko-and-codegust).